# When accessing a Category url is there direct access to the Category's fields?

Tags: categories, url

I have setup a category group to use Url's. When navigating to that url does the template have direct access to that category's inputs like you would with and entry? Or do you have to use the segment and get the data that way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the [CategoryModel](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/categorymodel) for your category will be available to the template as the variable `category`.

```
<h2 class="categoryTitle">{{ category.title }}</h2>
{{ dump(category) }}
```

Comment: Too fast.... :)

Comment: Its a tie. I think we'll need to see the server logs :)